# Minimum BoundingBox on n-dimensional case

Tags: cg.comp-geom

I need to develop an algorithm to define the minimum bounding box on an N-dimensional space.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box

Every reference to this problem that I'm able to find is related to computer graphics (so, only 2 or 3 dimensions). Where can I find some references on the generalised version of this problem?

Comment: If the bounds of the "box" are axis aligned, just use min and max values for each dimension. Or are you looking for arbitrarily aligned minimum bounding boxes?

Comment: Also, do you want an exact or approximate answer ?

Answer (score 8):

See chapter 18 here http://goo.gl/pLiEO. If the dimension is really high then bounding box is the wrong creature to work with. A better choice is the ellipsoid. See chapter 16 about John's ellipsoid - it can be computed efficiently using quadratic programming in some cases.

Comment: A minor point: I first viewed your answer on my phone, and I try not to download pdf's, etc., on my phone, so I didn't click your link because I wasn't sure what it would do.  (Nothing malicious, I know, just my own quirk here.)  Anyway, if you would consider adding a few words of explanation about your links, especially if they are short links, I'd appreciate it.